# Adding horizontal infinite scrolling to reactJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

Currently, I am trying to implement horizontal infinite scrolling in react project.
[image]
As shown in above image I want to add Infinite scroll, So I am not sure how to create infinite horizontal scrolling.

I have tried using `react-infinite-scroll-component` but it only supports **verical scrolling**

Comment: Did you check this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-infinite-scroll